# Can I use Isopods in a leopard gecko cage?

Tags: leopard-geckos, cleaning

I want an automated cleaning system for my leopard gecko cage so as to prepare for using soil in my cages later on.

Im wondering if its okay to use the little orange isopods that some people put in lizard cages.

- Will they eat them if they get really hungry
- Does it cause any negative effects on the cage?

Also if anyone else has time, does this account for Crested geckos too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the setup of your current cage? You mention doing so as a preparation for using soil, but if you don't currently use soil/a loose substrate they can live in you can't have isopods.
The leopard gecko can eat them yes.
As for crested geckos, I don't personally keep them, but I assume it'd work the same. The only problem I can see is that crested geckos are arboreal and therefore may not always defecate in areas the isopods can access easily.

Comment: Currently, its just a basic ZOO MED cage with all the goodies that come with + some extra life / rocks / hides. It doesnt even have substrate, which I want to consider. I could try getting some substrate, and then should I consider isopods? I already found a place that sells them called "Isopods Source"

Comment: @Tay Yeah you'll want to get the substrate and then introduce isopods. Gives them something to live in etc. The substrate I use for my leopard gecko enclosure is called Arcadia EarthMix Arid.